# Calculate the inscribed circle between one line and two circles

Tags: geometry

I am currently working on finding a calculation that will help me determine the values of $C_x$, $C_y$ and $C_r$ as shown in the image below.

The goal is for the unknown red circle to touch the line and be tangent to the two green circles.

[This](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/LCC.shtml#solution) website explains the situation as pointed out by [Intelligenti pauca](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651425/calculate-the-inscribed-circle-between-1-line-and-2-cirlces#comment9822027_4651425)

```
For example, the given values are:

C1r = 2
C1x = 2
C1y = 8
C2r = 2.5
C2x = 11
C2y = 9
P1x = 5
P1y = 0
P2x = 12
P2y = 3

The outcome should be somewhere around:
Cr = 3.671
Cx = 6.596
Cy = 4.678
```

[image]

**The worked out result in C# code**
(based on the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4654718/revisions))

```
    public static bool GetCircleFromLCC(out double C_x, out double C_y, out double C_radius)
    {
        // -- Input values --
        double C1_radius = 2;
        double C1_x = 2;
        double C1_y = 8;
        double C2_radius = 2.5;
        double C2_x = 11;
        double C2_y = 9;
        double P1_x = 5;
        double P1_y = 0;
        double P2_x = 12;
        double P2_y = 3;

        // -- Calculations --
        double u_x = P2_x - P1_x;
        double u_y = P2_y - P1_y;
        double norm = Math.Sqrt(u_x * u_x + u_y * u_y);
        u_x /= norm;
        u_y /= norm;
        double u1_x = -(u_x * P1_x + u_y * P1_y);
        double u1_y = -(-u_y * P1_x + u_x * P1_y);
        double u2_x = u_x * C1_x + u_y * C1_y;
        double u2_y = -u_y * C1_x + u_x * C1_y;
        double c1p_x = u2_x + u1_x;
        double c1p_y = u2_y + u1_y;
        u2_x = u_x * C2_x + u_y * C2_y;
        u2_y = -u_y * C2_x + u_x * C2_y;
        double c2p_x = u2_x + u1_x;
        double c2p_y = u2_y + u1_y;
        double a = 2.0 * (c1p_x - c2p_x);
        double b = 2.0 * (c1p_y - c2p_y + C1_radius - C2_radius);
        double c = Math.Pow(C1_radius, 2) - Math.Pow(C2_radius, 2) + Math.Pow(c2p_x, 2) - Math.Pow(c1p_x, 2) + Math.Pow(c2p_y, 2) - Math.Pow(c1p_y, 2);
        double a0 = Math.Pow(c1p_x, 2) + Math.Pow(c1p_y, 2) - Math.Pow(C1_radius, 2) + 2.0 * c / b * (c1p_y + C1_radius);
        double a1 = -2.0 * c1p_x + 2.0 * a / b * (C1_radius + c1p_y);
        double xdisc = Math.Pow(a1, 2) - 4.0 * a0;

        // Find quadratic roots
        if (xdisc > 0.00000001)
        {
            double root1 = (-a1 - Math.Sqrt(xdisc)) / 2;
            C_radius = 1 / b * (-c - a * root1);
            if (Math.Sign(C_radius) == Math.Sign(c1p_y) && Math.Sign(C_radius) == Math.Sign(c2p_y))
            {
                // Valid root, calculate the corresponding x,y coordinates
                u2_x = u_x * root1 + -u_y * C_radius;
                u2_y = u_y * root1 + u_x * C_radius;
                C_x = u2_x + P1_x;
                C_y = u2_y + P1_y;

                Console.WriteLine($"Solution 1   C_x: {C_x:0.0##}   y: {C_y:0.0##}   radius: {C_radius:0.0##}");
                // Solution 1   x: 6.596   y: 4.678   radius: 3.671
            }
            double root2 = (-a1 + Math.Sqrt(xdisc)) / 2;
            C_radius = 1 / b * (-c - a * root2);
            if (Math.Sign(C_radius) == Math.Sign(c1p_y) && Math.Sign(C_radius) == Math.Sign(c2p_y))
            {
                // Valid root, calculate the corresponding x,y coordinates
                u2_x = u_x * root2 + -u_y * C_radius;
                u2_y = u_y * root2 + u_x * C_radius;
                C_x = u2_x + P1_x;
                C_y = u2_y + P1_y;

                Console.WriteLine($"Solution 2   C_x: {C_x:0.0##}   y: {C_y:0.0##}   radius: {C_radius:0.0##}");
                // Solution 2   x: -48.359   y: 336.121   radius: 329.963
                return true;
            }
        }

        C_x = 0;
        C_y = 0;
        C_radius = 0;
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: This is a particular case of the Problem of Apollonius: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/LCC.shtml

Comment: Thanks! Didn’t know what it was called, looks clear with the illustrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Robert Israel solution, I am going to define a new reference frame with its origin at $P_1 = (5, 0) $, and its $u$ axis extending along $P_1 P_2 $

So the first coordinate vector is

$ \hat{u} = \dfrac{ P_2 - P_1 }{\| P_2 - P_1 \| } $

And the second coordinate vector is perpendicular to that

$ \hat{v} = [ - u_y , u_x ] $

Having defined the new coordinate system, express all the points with respect to this frame, this can be done as follows:

The relation between the coordinates in the $xy$ plane and $ uv $ plane is

$ P = P_1 + R Q $

So

$Q = R^T (P - P_1) $

where $R = [\hat{u} , \hat{v}] $

Apply this equation to $C_1, C_2, P_1, P_2 $ and name the new coordinates $C'_1, C'_2, P'_1, P'_2 $, so that

$ C'_1 = [u_1, v_1 ] $

$ C'_2 = [u_2, v_2 ] $

$P'_1 = [0, 0 ] $

$P'_2 = [ u_4, 0 ] $

**Note:** It is assumed that the circles are on the same side of the line segment.  If $v_1 \lt 0 $ and $v_2 \lt 0 $ then:  reverse the direction of vectors $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}$ and redefine the $R$ matrix, then redo the calculations for the computation of the coordinates in the $uv$ coordinate frame.

Next, let our center be expressed in the new reference frame be $ C' = (u, v) $, then it must satisfy

$ (u - u_1)^2 + (v - v_1)^2 = (r_1 + r)^2 $

$ (u - u_2)^2 + (v - v_2)^2 = (r_2 + r)^2 $

but the radius $r$ is equal to $v$, therefore,

$ (u - u_1)^2 + (v- v_1)^2 = (r_1 + v)^2 $

$ (u - u_2)^2 + (v - v_2)^2 = (r_2 + v)^2 $

Subtracting these two equations gives us

$ 2 u ( u_1 - u_2 ) + 2 v (v_1 - v_2 + r_1 - r_2) + r_1^2 - r_2^2 + u_2^2 - u_1^2 + v_2^2 - v_1^2 = 0 $

Solving for $v$ and substituting this equation $(3)$, one can determine the two solutions of $u$, and the corresponding values of $v$.  The sign of $v$ must be the same as the sign of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Having found the $(u, v)$ pair we can now calculate the $xy$ coordinates of the center from

$ P = P_1 + R Q $

I've implemented the above method into a VBA program on Excel.

Here's a listing of the subroutine.

```
Public Sub two_circles_and_a_line()
Dim r1, r2, c1(2), c2(2), p1(2), p2(2) As Double
Dim u(3), v(2) As Double
Dim r(2, 2) As Double, rt(2, 2) As Double
Dim c1p(2), c2p(2), p1p(2), p2p(2) As Double
Dim u1(2), u2(2) As Double
Dim roots(2) As Double

r1 = 2
r2 = 2.5

c1(1) = 2
c1(2) = 8

c2(1) = 11
c2(2) = 9

p1(1) = 5
p1(2) = 0

p2(1) = 12
p2(2) = 3

For i = 1 To 2
u(i) = p2(i) - p1(i)
Next i

Call normalize1(u)

v(1) = -u(2)
v(2) = u(1)

For i = 1 To 2
r(i, 1) = u(i)
r(i, 2) = v(i)
Next i

Call transpose(2, 2, r, rt)

' calculate coordinates in uv frame
p1p(1) = 0
p1p(2) = 0

Call multiplyv(2, 2, rt, p1, u1)

' negate u1
Call vscale(2, u1, -1, u1)

Call multiplyv(2, 2, rt, p2, u2)
Call vadd(2, u2, u1, p2p)

Call multiplyv(2, 2, rt, c1, u2)
Call vadd(2, u2, u1, c1p)

Call multiplyv(2, 2, rt, c2, u2)
Call vadd(2, u2, u1, c2p)

a = 2 * (c1p(1) - c2p(1))
b = 2 * (c1p(2) - c2p(2) + r1 - r2)
c = r1 ^ 2 - r2 ^ 2 + c2p(1) ^ 2 - c1p(1) ^ 2 + c2p(2) ^ 2 - c1p(2) 
^ 2

' now we have

' a u + b v + c = 0

' solve for v

'  v = 1/b ( - c - a u)

' substitute this into the distance equation

' (u - u1)^2 + (v - v1)^2 = (r1 + v )^2

' expanding and cancelling v^2 on both sides

' u^2 - 2 u1 u + u1^2 - 2 v v1 + v1^2 = r1^2 + 2 r1 v

' substitute  v = -1/b (a u + c )

' u^2 + u ( - 2 u1 + 2 a v1 / b + 2 a r1 / b ) + u1^2 + v1^2 - r1^2 
+ 2 v1 c / b + 2 r1 c / b = 0

a2 = 1
a1 = -2 * c1p(1) + 2 * a / b * (r1 + c1p(2))
a0 = c1p(1) ^ 2 + c1p(2) ^ 2 - r1 ^ 2 + 2 * c / b * (c1p(2) + r1)

Call find_quadratic_roots(a2, a1, a0, roots)
isol = 0

For i = 1 To roots(0)

u_ = roots(i)

v_ = 1 / b * (-c - a * u_)

If Sgn(v_) = Sgn(c1p(2)) And Sgn(v_) = Sgn(c2p(2)) Then

   isol = isol + 1

' valid root

' calculate the corresponding x,y coordinates

u1(1) = u_
u1(2) = v_

Call multiplyv(2, 2, r, u1, u2)

Call vadd(2, u2, p1, u3)

ActiveSheet.Cells(isol, 1) = u3(1)
ActiveSheet.Cells(isol, 2) = u3(2)
ActiveSheet.Cells(isol, 4) = v_

End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Here are the user defined subroutines that the above subroutines calls

```
Public Sub normalize1(x)
Dim xnorm As Double
xnorm = Sqr(x(1) ^ 2 + x(2) ^ 2 + x(3) ^ 2)

For j = 1 To 3
x(j) = x(j) / xnorm
Next j

End Sub

Public Sub transpose(ByVal m As Integer, 
ByVal n As Integer, a, At)
Dim c1(1500, 1500) As Double

' m  no. of rows of a
' n  no. of columns of a

For i = 1 To n
For j = 1 To m
c1(i, j) = a(j, i)
Next j
Next i


For i = 1 To n
For j = 1 To m
At(i, j) = c1(i, j)
Next j
Next i

End Sub

Public Sub multiplyv(n, m, a, b, c)
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim c1(200) As Double

For i = 1 To n
c1(i) = 0
For k = 1 To m
c1(i) = c1(i) + a(i, k) * b(k)
Next k

Next i


For i = 1 To n
c(i) = c1(i)
Next i

End Sub

Public Sub vadd(ByVal n As Integer, x, y, z)

For i = 1 To n
z(i) = x(i) + y(i)
Next i


End Sub

Public Sub vdiff(ByVal n As Integer, x, y, z)

For i = 1 To n
z(i) = x(i) - y(i)
Next i


End Sub

Public Sub vscale(ByVal n, x, a, y)

For i = 1 To n
y(i) = a * x(i)
Next i


End Sub

Public Sub find_quadratic_roots(a2, a1, a0, r)

If Abs(a2) > 0.0000001 Then

xdisc = a1 ^ 2 - 4 * a2 * a0

If xdisc < 0 And Abs(xdisc) < 0.00000001 Then xdisc = 0

If xdisc < 0 Then

  r(0) = 0
  
Else

  r(0) = 2
  r(1) = (-a1 - Sqr(xdisc)) / (2 * a2)
  r(2) = (-a1 + Sqr(xdisc)) / (2 * a2)
  
End If

Else

If Abs(a1) > 0.0000001 Then
  r(0) = 1
  r(1) = -a0 / a1
  
Else

  MsgBox ("Invalid Input in  Find_Quadratic_Roots")
  Exit Sub
  
End If
End If


End Sub
```

The output of the program is the following, where column $A$ is for the $x$ coordinate of the center and the $B$ column is for the $y$ coordinate.  Column $D$ lists the corresponding radius of the solution circle.  There were two valid solutions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's amazing :)
Did you wrote sub functions for the normalize1, transpose, multiplyv, vscale, ... your self in Excel or is this some kind of add-in?

Comment: No, it is not an add-in.  I wrote all these subroutines in VBA.

Comment: Could you provide those subroutines, so I can see what is happening inside? I'll try to make a C# version and post it in my question above.

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes to complete the Copy and Paste.

Comment: I have made a C# version out of it, works great! thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

For convenience, rotate the picture so the line is parallel to the $x$ axis, say $y = y_0$.  Now you want the centre of your third circle to be a point $C = (x,y)$ such that $\text{dist}(C, C_1) = r_1 + y - y_1$ and $\text{dist}(C, C_2) = r_2 + y - y_2$, where
$C_1 = (x_1, y_1)$, $C_2 = (x_2, y_2)$, and the given circles have radii $r_1$ and $r_2$.  Expanding $(x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2 = (r_1 + y - y_1)^2$ and simplifying
gives $x^2 - 2 x_1 x - 2 r_1 y + a_1 = 0$ where $a_1 =  x_1^2 + 2 r_1 y_1 - r_1^2$.
Similarly for the second circle you get $x^2 - 2 x_2 x - 2 r_2 y + a_2 = 0$.
You can then eliminate $y$ and solve a quadratic equation to get $x$.

Comment: Do the calculations become more complex when dealing with a line that is not horizontal?

Comment: +1 for this nice answer